# FreeRadius server is up but it doesn't log authentication tries

Tags: freeradius, radius

Hi I am using FreeRadius I have defined the following files: radiusd.conf, clients.conf and users
then I have set the firewall according to my needs:

1. ufw allow 1812/udp
2. ufw allow 1813/udp

I can reach to this server but I don't see any authentication failures in the radius.log and for sure I can't successfully authenticate my boxes with it.

I manage to use a TekRadius server successfully with my boxes so I know that my boxes are OK

What should I check in order to understand the point of failure ?
What might go wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get my server logging by changing some of the radiusd.conf settings to "yes":

```
log { 
auth = yes 
auth_badpass = yes 
auth_goodpass = yes 
}
```

Then I used: tail -f /var/log/freeradius/radius.log in order to see the log online